# C - Copying text from a file results in unknown characters being copied over as well

Tags: c, malloc, fgetc

When running the following C file, copying the character to `fgetc` to my tmp pointer results in unknown characters being copied over for some reason. The characters received from `fgetc()` are the expected characters. However, for some reason when assigning this character to my tmp pointer unknown characters get copied over.

I've tried looking for the reason why online, but haven't found any luck. From what I have read it could be something to do with UTF-8 and ASCII issues. However, I'm not sure about the fix. I'm a relatively new C programmer and still new to memory management.

Output:

```
TMP: Hello, DATA!�
TEXT: Hello, DATA!�
```

**game.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro5.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>

const int WIN_WIDTH = 1366;
const int WIN_HEIGHT = 768;

char *readFile(const char *fileName) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened for reading.\n");
    }

    size_t tmpSize = 1;
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(tmpSize);

    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("malloc() could not be called on tmp.\n");
    }

    for (int c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file)) {
        if (c != NULL) {
            if (tmpSize > 1)
                tmp = (char *)realloc(tmp, tmpSize);

            tmp[tmpSize - 1] = (char *)c;
            tmpSize++;
        }
    }
    tmp[tmpSize] = 0;

    fclose(file);
    printf("TMP: %s\n", tmp);
    return tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    al_init();
    al_install_keyboard();

    ALLEGRO_TIMER* timer = al_create_timer (1.0 / 30.0);
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *queue = al_create_event_queue();

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display = al_create_display(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT);
    ALLEGRO_FONT* font = al_create_builtin_font();

    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));

    int redraw = 1;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT event;

    al_start_timer(timer);

    char *text = readFile("game.DATA");
    printf("TEXT: %s\n", text);

    while (1) {
        al_wait_for_event(queue, &event);
        if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
            redraw = 1;
        else if ((event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN) || (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE))
            break;
        
        if (redraw && al_is_event_queue_empty(queue)) {
            al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
            al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 0, 0, 0, text);
            al_flip_display();

            redraw = false;
        }
    }

    free(text);
    al_destroy_font(font);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_event_queue(queue);

    return 0;
}
```

**game.DATA** file:

```
Hello, DATA!
```

What I use to run the program:

```
gcc game.c -o game $(pkg-config allegro-5 allegro_font-5 --libs --cflags)
```

--EDIT--

I tried taking the file reading code and running it in a new c file, for some reason it works there, but not when in the game.c file with allegro code.

**test.c**:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *readFile(const char *fileName) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened for reading.\n");
    }

    size_t tmpSize = 1;
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(tmpSize);

    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("malloc() could not be called on tmp.\n");
    }

    for (int c = fgetc(file); c != EOF; c = fgetc(file)) {
        if (c != NULL) {
            if (tmpSize > 1)
                tmp = (char *)realloc(tmp, tmpSize);

            tmp[tmpSize - 1] = (char *)c;
            tmpSize++;
        }
    }
    tmp[tmpSize] = 0;

    fclose(file);
    printf("TMP: %s\n", tmp);
    return tmp;
}

void main() {
    char *text = readFile("game.DATA");
    printf("TEXT: %s\n", text);

    free(text);
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the correct output always:

```
TMP: Hello, DATA!
TEXT: Hello, DATA!
```

Comment: Hello, please provide a [mcve] to help answerer to focus on the specific issue.

Comment: It's a bit silly to check the return value of `malloc` when you don't check `realloc`. If you're not checking both you may as well check neither. That aside, it looks like you're probably not allocating enough space for the string, and Allegro is stepping on the terminating zero-byte. I'd double-check that `realloc` loop, it seems fishy.

Comment: Not your problem, but: you don't want this: `if (c != NULL)`.

Comment: Also not your problem, but you don't want the cast in `tmp[tmpSize-1] = (char *) c`.  Just use `tmp[tmpSize-1] = c;`.

Comment: `File could not be opened for reading.` is the canonical example of a useless error message. Try:  `file = fopen(fileName, "r"); if (file == NULL) {perror(fileName); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a loop that updates various things each time through, like you do with `tmpSize` in your loop here, it's important to have a handle on what the theoretical computer science types call your "[loop invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant)".  That is, what is it that's true each time through the loop?  It's important not only to maintain your loop invariants properly, but also to *pick* your loop invariants so that they're easy to maintain, and easy for a later reader to understand and to verify.

Since `tmpSize` starts out as 1, I'm guessing your loop invariant is trying to be, "`tmpSize` is always one more than the size of the string I've read so far".  A reason for picking that slightly-strange loop invariant is, of course, that you'll need that extra byte for the terminating `\0`.  The other clue is that you're setting `tmp[tmpSize-1] = c;`.

But here's the first problem.  When we exit the loop, and if `tmpSize` is still one more than the size of the string you've read so far, let's see what happens.  Suppose we read three characters.  So `tmpSize` should be 4.  So we'll set `tmp[4] = 0;`.  But wait!  Remember, arrays in C are 0-based.  So the three characters we read are in `tmp[0]`, `tmp[1]`, and `tmp[2]`, and we want the terminating `\0` character to go into `tmp[3]`, not `tmp[4]`.  Something is wrong.

But actually, it's worse than that.  I wasn't at all sure I understood the loop invariant, so I cheated, and inserted a few debugging printouts.  Right before the `realloc` call, I added

```
printf("realloc %zu\n", tmpSize);
```

and at the end, right before the `tmp[tmpSize] = 0;` line, I added

```
printf("final %zu\n", tmpSize);
```

The last few lines it printed (while reading a game.DATA file containing "Hello, DATA!" just like yours) were:

```
...
realloc 10
realloc 11
realloc 12
final 13
```

But this is off by *two*!  If the last reallocation gave the array a size of 12, the valid indices are from 0 to 11.  But somehow we end up writing the `\0` into cell 13.

It took me a while to figure it out, but the second problem is that you do the reallocation at the top of the loop, before you've incremented `tmpLen`.

To me, the loop invariant of "one more than the size of the string read so far" is just too hard to think about.  I very much prefer to use a loop invariant where the "size" variable keeps track of the number of characters I *have* read, not +1 or -1 off of that.  Let's see how that loop might look.  (I've also cleaned up a few other things.)

```
size_t tmpSize = 0;
char *tmp = malloc(tmpSize+1);
if (tmp == NULL) {
    printf("malloc() failed.\n");
    exit(1);
}

for (int c = getc(file); c != EOF; c = getc(file)) {
    printf("realloc %zu\n", tmpSize+1+1);
    tmp = realloc(tmp, tmpSize+1+1);        /* +1 for c, +1 for \0 */
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("realloc() failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    tmp[tmpSize] = c;
    tmpSize++;
}

printf("final %zu\n", tmpSize);
tmp[tmpSize] = '\0';
```

There's still something fishy here -- I said I didn't like "fudge factors" like +1, and here I've got *two* -- but at least now the debugging printouts go

```
...
realloc 11
realloc 12
realloc 13
final 12
```

so it looks like I'm not overrunning the allocated memory any more.

To make this even better, I want to take a slightly different approach.  You're not supposed to worry abut efficiency at first, but I can tell you that a loop that calls `realloc` to make the buffer bigger by 1, each time it reads a character, can end up being *really* inefficient.  So let's make a few more changes:

```
size_t nchAllocated = 0;
size_t nchRead = 0;
char *tmp = NULL;

for (int c = getc(file); c != EOF; c = getc(file)) {
    if(nchAllocated <= nchRead) {
        nchAllocated += 10;
        printf("realloc %zu\n", nchAllocated);
        tmp = realloc(tmp, nchAllocated);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            printf("realloc() failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    tmp[nchRead++] = c;
}

printf("final %zu\n", nchRead);
tmp[nchRead] = '\0';
```

Now there are two separate variables: `nchAllocated` keeps track of exactly how many characters I've allocated, and `nchRead` keeps track of exactly how many characters I've read.  And although I've doubled the number of "counter" variables, in doing so I've simplified a lot of other things, so I think it's a net improvement.

First of all, notice that there are no +1 fudge factors any more, at all.

Second, this loop doesn't call `realloc` every time -- instead it allocates characters 10 at a time.  And because there are separate variables for the number of characters allocated versus read, it can keep track of the fact that it may have allocated more characters than it has read so far.  For this code, the debugging printouts are:

```
realloc 10
realloc 20
final 12
```

Another little improvement is that we don't have to "preallocate" the array -- there's no initial `malloc` call.  One of our loop invariants is that `nchAllocated` is the number of characters allocated, and we start this out as 0, and if there are no characters allocated, then it's okay that `tmp` starts out as NULL.  This relies on the fact that when you call `realloc` for the first time, with `tmp` equal to `NULL`, `realloc` is fine with that, and essentially acts like `malloc`.

But there's one question you might be asking: If I got rid of all my fudge factors, where do we arrange to allocate one extra byte to hold the terminating `\0` character?  It's there, but it's subtle: it's lurking in the test

```
if(nchAllocated <= nchRead)
```

The very first time through the loop, `nchAllocated` will be 0, and `nchRead` will be 0, but this test will be true, so we'll allocate our first chunk of 10 characters, and we're off and running.  (If we didn't care about the `\0` character, the test `nchAllocated < nchRead` would have sufficed.)

...But, actually, I've made a mistake!  There's a subtle bug here!

What if the file being read is empty?  `tmp` will start out `NULL`, and we'll never make any trips through the loop, so `tmp` will remain `NULL`, so when we assign `tmp[nchRead] = 0` it'll blow up.

And actually, it's worse than that.  If you trace through the logic very carefully, you'll find that any time the file size is an exact multiple of 10, not enough space gets allocated for the `\0`, after all.

And this indicates a significant drawback of the "allocate characters 10 at a time" scheme.  The code is now harder to test, because the control flow is different for files whose size is a multiple of 10.  If you never happen to test that case, you won't realize that this program has a bug in it.

The way I usually fix this is to notice that the `\0` byte I have to add to terminate the string is sort of balanced by the `EOF` character I read that indicated the end of the file.  Maybe, when I read the `EOF`, I can use it to remind me to allocate space for the `\0`.  That's actually easy enough to do, and it looks like this:

```
int c;
while(1) {
    c = getc(file);
    if(nchAllocated <= nchRead) {
        nchAllocated += 10;
        printf("realloc %zu\n", nchAllocated);
        tmp = realloc(tmp, nchAllocated);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            printf("realloc() failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if(c == EOF)
        break;

    tmp[nchRead++] = c;
}

printf("final %zu\n", nchRead);
tmp[nchRead] = '\0';
```

The trick here is that we don't test for `EOF` until *after* we've checked that there's enough space in the buffer, and called `realloc` if necessary.  It's as if we allocate space in the buffer for the `EOF` -- except then we use that space for the `\0` instead.  This is what I meant by "use it to remind me to allocate space for the `\0`".

Now, I have to admit that there's still a drawback here, in that the loop is now somewhat unconventional.  A loop that has `while(1)` at the top looks like an infinite loop.  This one has

```
if(c == EOF) break;
```

down in the middle of it, so it is literally a "break in the middle" loop.  (This is by contrast to conventional `for` and `while` loops, which are "break at the top", or a `do`/`while` loop, which is "break at the bottom".)  Personally, I find this to be a useful idiom, and I use it all the time.  But some programmers, and perhaps your instructor, would frown on it, because it's "weird", it's "different", it's "unconventional".  And to some extent they're right: unconventional programming is somewhat dangerous programming, and is bad if later maintenance programmers can't understand it because they don't recognize or don't understand the idioms in it.  (It's sort of the programming equivalent of the English word "ain't", or a split infinitive.)

Finally, if you're still with me, I have one more point to make.  (And if you are still with me, thank you.  I realize this answer has gotten *very* long, but I hope you're learning something.)

Earlier I said that "a loop that calls `realloc` to make the buffer bigger by 1, each time it reads a character, can end up being really inefficient."  It turns out that a loop that makes the buffer bigger by 10 isn't much better, and can still be significantly inefficient.  You can do a little better by incrementing it by 50 or 100, but if you're dealing with input that might be really big (thousands of characters or more), you're usually better off increasing the buffer size by leaps and bounds, perhaps by *multiplying* it by some factor, rather than adding.  So here's the final version of that part of the loop:

```
    if(nchAllocated <= nchRead) {
        if(nchAllocated == 0) nchAllocated = 10;
        else nchAllocated *= 2;
    printf("realloc %zu\n", nchAllocated);
    tmp = realloc(tmp, nchAllocated);
```

And even this improvement -- multiplying by 2, rather than adding something -- comes with a cost: we need an extra test, to special-case the first trip through the loop, because `nchAllocated` started out as 0, and 0 × 2 = 0.

Comment: Thanks for the long response, realise I've got a lot to learn when it comes to memory management so will continue to study more on it. Learned a lot from the response though, thanks.

Comment: @connorwmackay Glad you made it all the way through.  And I hope you're not overwhelmed or dismayed by it.  This reply might make it look like the problem of "reading a file into dynamically-allocated memory" is nearly impossible: But no, it's not, and indeed once you know what you have to be careful of it's perfectly straightforward. But you **do** need to know a few things to be careful of.  That's pretty much the nature of C programming.

Answer (score 4):

Your reallocation scheme is incorrect: the array is always too short by one byte and the null terminator is written one position past the end of the string, instead of at the end of the string. This causes an extra byte to be printed, with whatever value happens to be in memory in the block returned by `realloc()`, which is uninitialized.

It is less confusing to use `tmpLen` as the length of the string read si far and allocate 2 extra bytes for the newly read character and the null terminator.

Furthermore the test `c != NULL` makes no sense: `c` is  byte and `NULL` is a pointer. Similarly, `tmp[tmpSize - 1] = (char *)c;` is incorrect: you should just write

```
tmp[tmpSize - 1] = c;
```

Here is a corrected version:

```
char *readFile(const char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened for reading.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t tmpLen = 0;
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(tmpLen + 1);

    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("malloc() could not be called on tmp.\n");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        char *new_tmp = (char *)realloc(tmp, tmpLen + 2);
        if (new_tmp == NULL) {
            printf("realloc() failure for %zu bytes.\n", tmpLen + 2);
            free(tmp);
            fclose(file);
            return NULL;
        }
        tmp = new_tmp;
        tmp[tmpLen++] = c;
    }
    tmp[tmpLen] = '\0';

    fclose(file);
    printf("TMP: %s\n", tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

It is usually better to reallocate in chunks or with a geometric size increment. Here is a simple implementation:

```
char *readFile(const char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened for reading.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t tmpLen = 0;
    size_t tmpSize = 16;
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(tmpSize);
    char *newTmp;

    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("malloc() could not be called on tmp.\n");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (tmpSize - tmpLen < 2) {
            size_t newSize = tmpSize + tmpSize / 2;
            newTmp = (char *)realloc(tmp, newSize);
            if (newTmp == NULL) {
                printf("realloc() failure for %zu bytes.\n", newSize);
                free(tmp);
                fclose(file);
                return NULL;
            }
            tmpSize = newSize;
            tmp = newTmp;
        }
        tmp[tmpLen++] = c;
    }
    tmp[tmpLen] = '\0';

    fclose(file);
    printf("TMP: %s\n", tmp);

    // try to shrink allocated block to the minimum size
    // if realloc() fails, return the current block
    // it seems impossible for this reallocation to fail
    // but the C Standard allows it.
    newTmp = (char *)realloc(tmp, tmpLen + 1);
    return newTmp ? newTmp : tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, definitely need to read into memory management more so will start doing that

Comment: @connorwmackay: very good point. Understanding memory management and more generally memory usage is key to mastering pointers, data structures, complexity, avoiding bloat and leakage. This knowledge is a strong advantage when moving to other languages where data representation is abstracted from programmers and out of their control.